# Create audio stream based on other audio streams

Tags: ruby, proxy, streaming, audio-streaming, shoutcast

is it possible to create a live audio stream based on other audio streams? I'm thinking of a proxy that gets two audio streams (e.g. shoutcast stream), and based on time, switches to one of them. And, if its possible, to have some time for analysis, I would implement some kind of caching so that I can stream the newly created stream time-displaced.

I already had a look on the Shoutcast server but couldn't figure out, how to config the input source as another stream. Maybe there are other projects that can handle this through a interface.

Programming language don't really matters, but Ruby is prefered.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You need to stitch the streams together yourself.  How you do this depends on the codecs used.

Comment: I'm currently trying with shoutcast streams, but I don't know the codecs they are using. Do you have an example for me?

Comment: Play the stream in VLC, right click, and click media info to figure out what the codec is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own solution with javascript based on nodejs. You can clone the repo (a personal radio app) at https://github.com/23tux/personal_node_radio.